# > Could not find com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:1.0.18

Tags: flutter

i get new device and setup my android studio it work good when run old project iget this error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.umair13adil:RxLogs:1.0.18.
> Searched in the following locations:

```
 Required by:
     project :app > project :flutter_logs
```

i try edit gradle classpath and implementation flutetr logs in app/gradle

Comment: same error when run the project

Comment: if you have solution then share it with me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77618638/20519146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also undergone the same issue before.

Instead of installing any RxLogs specific dependency, follow the process:

- delete pubspec.lock file
- run flutter clean
- run flutter pub get

Also update to Kotlin latest version in android/build.gradle in case you don't have.

Hope this will help you.